# How to keep effect on main tab, when hovering on the dropdown menu, same as hovering effect on main tab?

Tags: html, css

I want to make dropdown menu. I have coded one in html/css but when I hover on the dropdown menu, the effect on the main tab changes. I want that the main tab should look same as when hovered, while hovering on dropdown menu. Please solve out my problem!

Below is my css code:-

```
#main {
margin: auto;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
border-right: solid 1px black;
float: left;
text-align: center;
font-size: 30;
color: #E17D10;
}

#main:hover {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2E8D3B, #39B54A);
color: black;
}

.drop {
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
visibility: hidden;
background: white;
width: 33.3%;
top: 100%;
}

#main:hover+.drop, .drop:hover {
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
visibility: visible;
background: white;
width: 33.3%;
top: 100%;
background: white;
color: black;
font-size: 20;
}
```

Below is my html code:-

```
<div id="mainmenu">
<div id="main">
Explore
</div>
<nav class="drop">
<li><a href="">Country</a></li>
<li>State</li>
<li>City</li>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using hover on #main use it on #mainmenu like this 
`#mainmenu:hover #main {}`

as both .drop and #main are in #mainmenu ,it will stay the same color if you move your mouse to .drop

Comment: Excellent answer. If anyone wants to do this for bootstrap, apple the hover to the .dropdown class (the li) and then reference the a tag, so it looks like this: .dropdown:hover .dropdown-toggle {your styles}